# xmlXPathFreeContext api is crashing a few times

Tags: libxml2

I have a piece of code that executes fine sometimes and few times it is crashing. crash occurs at XML api xmlXPathFreeContext.

Not an expert in XML, so no idea how to debug this.

```
xmlXPathObjectPtr SIQXmlParser::getnodeset (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlChar *xpath)
{

    xmlXPathContextPtr context;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;

    context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if (context == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathNewContext\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    result = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(context);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
        xmlXPathFreeObject(result);
                printf("No result\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This cannot be answered without further information (stack trace of the crash, minimal reproducible example code + input).